# Facebook callback when user likes a post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have an iOS app that posts to the users Facebook timeline. Is there a way to get notified whenever  this post is being liked?

I.e. User X clicks on Like, Facebook calls something like http://example.com/liked?post=1234&by=5678

If not, does the Graph API offer some way to monitor the users graph?

Comment: Why do you need it? It is not possible

Comment: Client project: user can post stuff to Facebook, the iOS app will react whenever someone of the users friends Likes that post.